# Polymorphism in Angular6

Tags: oop, polymorphism, angular6

I want to know if any OOP concepts are followed in front end languages .

Does in Angular 6, we have a concept of Polymorphism?
Any example and theory will work. I just need to understand whether there is any concept of Polymorphism in Angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Not in Angular 6 itself, but in the language TypeScript that is used by the framework. You get polymorphism via sub-typing and type inference.